# Why does R's attributes() function fail when using explicit arguments?

Tags: r, attributes

I am working with `RODBC` and `parallel` to make multiple queries against a data system for some internal reporting. To facilitate making new connections, I am going to extract the connection string from the `RODBC` object. To do this, I planned to use `attributes()`. However, I've encountered a behavior that I do not understand. A minimal working example is below:

```
> example.data <- data.frame(letters = sample(x = LETTERS,size = 20,replace = T),
+                            numbers = sample(x = 0:9,size = 20,replace = T))
> 
> attributes(obj = example.data)
Error in attributes(obj = example.data) : 
  supplied argument name 'obj' does not match 'x'
> attributes(example.data)
$names
[1] "letters" "numbers"

$row.names
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20

$class
[1] "data.frame"
```

It should be noted that the `obj =` behavior is the one tab-suggested by RStudio. However, it causes an error. I tried to review the source code for `attributes`, but it is a primitive, so I would have to go digging into the C source - with which I am not nearly as familiar.

Why does `attributes()` fail when an explicit argument (`obj =`) is used, but runs fine when it is not used? (And should the behavior of RStudio with regard to suggesting `obj =` be changed?)

Comment: Good find. Interestingly, it does work with `attributes(x = ...)`, so it seems someone at R Core may have forgotten to change something.  But normally one would not use `obj =` anyway, since that is the only argument to `attributes()`

Comment: Not exactly sure where on the page we should be looking, but here is [attrib.c](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/f42ee5e7ecf89a245afd6619b46483f1e3594ab7/src/main/attrib.c#L1190).  I think it's `do_attributes` but I'm not sure.  We need someone named Joshua.

Comment: huh, for some reason it checks that the argument is called "x" via `Rf_check1arg`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems like a bug in the documentation for attributes. The parameter probably should be named `x`. You can call it that way

```
attributes(x = example.data)
```

The problem is that `attributes()` is a primitive function and primitive functions behave differently than regular functions in R. They don't have formal parameters (`formals(attributes)` returns `NULL`). For these types of functions, R typically isn't going to parse out parameters by name and will assume they are in a certain positional order for efficiency reasons. That's why it's better not to name them because you cannot change the order of these parameters. There should be no need to name the parameter here.

There are other functions out there that have mismatches between the parameter name in the documentation and the value checked by the code. For example

```
isS4(pi)
# [1] FALSE
# documented parameter name is "object"
isS4(object=pi)
# Error in isS4(object = pi) : 
#   supplied argument name 'object' does not match 'x'
isS4(x=pi)
# [1] FALSE
```

But there are also other primitives out there that use names other than `x`: e.g. `seq_along` (uses "along.with=") and `quote` (uses "expr=").